# Java JRebel vs MyRebel licence plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, licensing, jrebel

I'm thinking to buy a licence for `JRebel` the product from `ZeroTurnaround` sounds very good but I have a questions on it..

Which are the differences between a `JRebel` and `MyJRebel`

The official sites says.

`MyJRebel brings these capabilities to you for free for personal, non-commercial use only. All you need to do is allow sharing your usage statistics on a social network.`

my questions....

1) I wonder how the plugins knows if the project is a non-commercial one. Sorry if this question is silly because sounds that everybody would use MyJRebel and not buy JRebel?

2) Which are the differences between both?

3) JRebel are more sophisticated than MyJRebel?

4) Can I use the same licence in two or more projects in differents IDES [netbeans, eclipse]

5) What if I re-install my windows, linux, eclipse, netbeans would have any problems setting my valid licence?

I would like to hear if you can share you experiences with JRebel if you use it with me.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is exactly what is mentioned at the product web site: MyJRebel is for non-commercial use only.

The plugin doesn't know if you're using it for commercial development or not. Only you know that. Just that if you're using MyJRebel license for commercial development it means that you're pirating the software, that's it - most of the developers don't like to be called pirates :)

And there's no difference in functionality between JRebel commercial and MyJRebel licenses - both can reload same kind of changes you make in the code and framework configurations. You can use the same license in different IDEs exactly the same way as if you would use the commercial license.

Comment: yes pirates is not a good thing... best regards.. i will become a rebel soon.. thanks.